# How to correctly create a web socket connection client in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, websocket, java-websocket, grizzly

I can't establish a correct connection to the topic. The server has a spring boot running and a web socket is configured in it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    private MessageBrokerRegistry registry;
   
   @Override    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/news")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/events")        ;
    }
    public MessageBrokerRegistry getRegistry() {
        return this.registry;    }
}
```

I made a simple application in JavaFX, which should connect to a socket when launched.

I'll show you the specific code from the application that is responsible for the connection, I think this will be enough.

Libraries used in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-client:${tyrusVersion}")
    compileOnly("jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-client-api:${jakartaSocketVersion}")
    compileOnly("jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-api:${jakartaSocketVersion}")
    implementation ("org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly-client:${tyrusVersion}")
    implementation("org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:${grizzlyHttpVersion}")
    implementation("jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:${jakartaWSVersion}")
    implementation("org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:${grizzlyHttpVersion}")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:3.1.3")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1")
    implementation("jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:2.0.1")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:3.1.3")
    implementation("jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.2")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:3.1.3")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2")
    implementation("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0")
    implementation("jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.1.2")
}
```

Class that implements the connection:

```
ClientEndpoint(configurator = CustomClientEndpointConfigurator.class,
        decoders = MessageDecoder.class,
        encoders = MessageEncoder.class
)
public class BasicClient implements MessageHandler {

    private final URI uri;
    private static BasicClient instance;
    private Session session;
    private final List<EventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isOpen;
    private MessageHandler handler;

    public BasicClient(URI uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public static synchronized BasicClient getInstance() throws URISyntaxException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BasicClient(new URI(createURISocketEDMS()));
       }
       return instance;
   }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        client.connectToServer(this, uri);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        this.session = session;
        String[] strings = new String[1];
        strings[0] = "\"SUBSCRIBE id:sub-34 destination:/events\"";
        session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(Arrays.toString(strings));
        try {
            Logging.log("Opening connection");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logging.log("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage() + " INFORMATION: " +    BasicClient.class.getName());
        }
    }

    public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
        this.handler = msgHandler;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) throws IOException {
        WebSocketEvent webSocketEvent = new WebSocketEvent(WebSocketEvent.DISCONNECTED);
        this.session = null;
        notifyListeners(webSocketEvent);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @OnMessage
    public void processMessage(Message message, Session session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Received message in client: " + message+" "+session.getId());
        if (this.handler != null)
            this.handler.handleMessage(message);
        WebSocketEvent webSocketEvent = new WebSocketEvent(WebSocketEvent.MSG);
        notifyListeners(webSocketEvent);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) throws IOException {
        WebSocketEvent webSocketEvent = new WebSocketEvent(WebSocketEvent.ERROR);
        notifyListeners(webSocketEvent);
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        String[] strings1 = new String[1];
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            strings1[0] = String.format("\"CONNECT %s\"", message);
            this.session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(Arrays.toString(strings1));
        }

    }

    public void addListener(EventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    private void notifyListeners(WebSocketEvent event) throws IOException {
        for (EventListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.handleEvent(event);
        }
    }

    public boolean isSession() {
        return isOpen;
    }

    public interface MessageHandler {
        void handleMessage(Message message);
    }
}
```

Classes such as: `CustomClientEndpointConfigurator`, `MessageDecoder`, `MessageEncoder` - are by default and do not contain complex logic that can affect the operation of the connection, but if you know that something can be improved there, then please let me know.

The method call goes here:

```
public class GeneralController {

private BasicClient basicClient;

    @FXML
    void initialize() throws IOException {
        try {

           basicClient = BasicClient.getInstance();
           basicClient.connect();
 
           basicClient.addListener(event -> {

                if (event.getEventType() == WebSocketEvent.DISCONNECTED) {
                    indicatorConnect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");

                } else if (event.getEventType() == WebSocketEvent.CONNECTED) {
                    indicatorConnect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");

                } else if (event.getEventType() == WebSocketEvent.ERROR) {
                    indicatorConnect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                }else if(event.getEventType() == WebSocketEvent.MSG){

                    basicClient.addMessageHandler(new BasicClient.MessageHandler(){
                        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                            System.out.println("handleMessage " + message);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
   } catch (Exception e) {
            indicatorConnect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I succeeded in connecting, but the following appears in the console:

```
{connection=[upgrade], date=[Sat, 09 Sep 2023 09:05:48 GMT], sec-websocket-accept=[SrlO1lcA+TvLUnZ/J54X1dEQiiw=], upgrade=[websocket]}null
nullOpening connection. Open session: true
Initializing message decoder
Received message in client: Message[message=o] f1410a67-0362-43ae-bfae-20a52b2d33bd
Received message in client: Message[message=h] f1410a67-0362-43ae-bfae-20a52b2d33bd
handleMessage Message[message=h]
Received message in client: Message[message=h] f1410a67-0362-43ae-bfae-20a52b2d33bd 
handleMessage Message[message=h]
Received message in client: Message[message=h] f1410a67-0362-43ae-bfae-20a52b2d33bd
handleMessage Message[message=h]
```

That is, the letter “o” comes first from the server, after which the letters “h” arrive. Although other messages should arrive, in the form of text, nothing comes except these letters. And so on endlessly.

Please tell me where to look for the problem? I don’t see any errors, it seems like a successful connection, but incorrectly receiving messages from the socket (server). There may be a problem on the server or on the client.

I connected to some sockets for an experiment, one of them: `wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv`, and the messages are coming the same.

If you connect to my server (spirng boot) using the frontend (angular), then ready-made libraries are used and when connected it changes the appearance of the URL, from `domain.com/soket` to `domain.com/socket/142/werwerw/websocket`. I had to do this in code because I couldn’t just connect, the spring boot required a certain type of checkpoint. method `createURISocketEDMS()`:

```
  public static final String LOCALHOST_WEBSOCKET_CONNECT = "/socket/%s/%s/websocket";
  public static String createURISocketEDMS() throws URISyntaxException {
       PropBuilder propBuilder = PropBuilder.getInstance();
       if (propBuilder.getHostWS() == null) {
          return null;
       }
       String username = resultServer.getDetails().getPrincipal().getUsername();
       String valueStr = generateStringEndpoint();

       return String.format("ws://localhost:8080"+LOCALHOST_WEBSOCKET_CONNECT,username,valueStr); 

    }

  private static String generateStringEndpoint() {

      Long value = resultServer.getDetails().getPrincipal().getId();

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(value).append("_");
      Random random = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
         int index = random.nextInt(ALPHABET.length());
         sb.append(ALPHABET.charAt(index));
      }
      return sb.toString();
   }
```

Thereby creating an endpoint through which the spring boot connected to the client application. But maybe I’m doing something wrong and there is another way to correctly connect to the topik and receive messages from the server.

I need to subscribe to: `/events`, but I dont know how. Sending a subscription message `"strings1[0] = String.format("\"CONNECT %s\"", message);"` - doesn't work.

Comment: My advice as you have no idea what is going wrong and the question is way too complex for StackOverflow, is to start from [working code from the Spring WebSocket tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/), then gradually modify it a bit at a time to get closer and closer to what you want to achieve, thoroughly testing at each step to ensure you haven’t broken something.  If you do this correctly you will eventually, after much hard work and effort, achieve what you want.

Comment: The tutorial I referenced is for a server, there are similar tutorials [for clients](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client), for which you can follow the same approach.

Comment: As part of following jewelsea's advice, try to get the client to work _before_ integrating it with JavaFX. That way you know if the problem is with the client or the integration. It also simplifies things. If you don't have to think about JavaFX while coding the client, then there's less stuff to potentially cause confusion.

Comment: @jewelsea I just tried the linked example, and it is not working. Maybe it was working once, but note anymore.

Comment: @KrizsánBalazs I provided two links in comments.  Which example did you try?  The [official guide from spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket), or the [guide from baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client)?  What does not working mean?  Is there an exception or incorrect behavior that you can describe.  If you continue to have issues, you can ask a new question with the details of what you tried and how it failed.  Or, if you think there are errors in the tutorials, you can contact the tutorial maintainers and request a fix.